# How Mod Rewrite interacts with logs

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite, logging

I'm using CakePHP, and I'm not understanding how mod_rewrite affects custom logs.

In `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

(index.php is where CakePHP starts to route the request)

And then in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
  LogFormat "%U %q" custom

  CustomLog "/var/log/apache/custom.log" custom
```

But for a request /foo?bar=1, I see

```
/foo ?url=foo&bar=1
```

I don't understand what is happening.

It seems like the log happens before rewrite with `%U`, but **AFTER** rewrite with `%q`. Is this expected behavior? Can I change it? (There are severe limits on my log size, and logging every path twice is undesirable.)

Comment: Quite interesting. I would say this is a bug in Apache worth reporting. It does make some sense in a way that it would act like this but yeah, I still think it wasn't intended to work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what Apache is doing here, but I can get CakePHP to work without using the query string at all:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L,NE,E=URL:$1]
```

And then in `index.php`:

```
$_GET['url'] = substr(getenv('REDIRECT_URL'), 1);
```

This seems a lot less hacky anyway than the normal CakePHP way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to go about it to look what mod_rewrite is doing; you need to see whats going on in the rewrite process. You need to enable rewrite log in order to accurately see what's going on in there:

The code is:

```
RewriteLog "/usr/local/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log"
```

You'll need to then restart apache considering you have the rewrite module enabled. This is going to help you in debugging. In addition, you have to put this in the virtual host entry.

Comment: I'm not trying to know what `mod_rewrite` is doing. I am trying to get access logs that *don't* include duplicate data. (Due to size constraints on logs.)